# Oracle SQL Cursor to increase salaries until the max amount is reached

Tags: sql, oracle, cursor, procedure

For this problem I need to increase employees.salary by 20% starting with the lowest salaries(asc order) until $100,000 is exhausted. I'm having difficulty finding a solution on how to save the updated amount left until $100,000 has been used. This is what I have so far. Thank you

```
declare
 cursor mancur is
   select salary from employees order by salary asc;
 tempcur     mancur%ROWTYPE;
 profits     number := 100000;
 tempsalary  employees.salary%type;
 tempinc     number(8,2);
begin
 open mancur;
 loop
   fetch mancur into tempcur;
   tempinc := tempcur.salary * 1.20;
   tempsalary := profits - tempcur.salary;
   dbms_output.put_line(tempcur.salary || ' increased by 20% ' || tempinc || ', Bonus amount left ' || tempsalary);
   exit when mancur%notfound; --when 100,000 has been used
   --update employees set salary = salary * 1.20 where employee_id = tempcur.employee_id;
 end loop;
 close mancur;
end;
/
```

Comment: Is this a production problem or a homework problem? If it is homework, is it for a PL/SQL class? This requirement can be solved much more efficiently with a single SQL statement.

Comment: Also, how do you handle ties? Suppose you went up the list, and now the next employees (whose salary hasn't been increased yet) are THREE employees with the same salary. Their current salary is $30,000 each, so they should receive $6,000 each, but there is only $12,000 left. Who gets how much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
begin
 open mancur;
  loop
   fetch mancur into tempcur;
   tempinc := tempcur.salary * 1.20;
   profits := profits - (tempinc-tempcur.salary);  -- You have to keep subtracting the increment amount to find if bonus is exhausted or not
      if profits <=0 Then  --When all your funds are exhausted
         Exit
      End if
              dbms_output.put_line(tempcur.salary || ' increased by 20% ' || tempinc || ', Bonus amount left ' || profits);
      exit when mancur%notfound; --when 100,000 has been used
   --update employees set salary = salary * 1.20 where employee_id = 
      tempcur.employee_id;
   end loop;
 close mancur;
end;
/
```

Comment: Thank you! Idk how I couldn't get that. Time to take a break from the screen ha

Answer (score 0):

```
declare
 profits     number := 100000;
 tempinc     number(8,2);
begin
for hike_loop in (select employee_id,salary from employees order by salary asc) loop
if profits <= 0 then
break;
end if;
tempinc := hike_loop.salary * 0.20;
if (tempinc <= profits) then
update employees set salary = salary * 1.20 where employee_id = hike_loop.employee_id;
profits := profits - tempinc;
else
break;
end if;
end loop;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun: here is how this should be done in plain SQL. There is no need for functions or procedures for this task, unless it's homework in a PL/SQL class. And even then, the same `MERGE` statement should be run from the PL/SQL code, so that the processing is done at the set level, not row by row.

This also solves for the "small remaining amount" differently from the solutions posted so far. If there isn't enough to increase the "last" salary by 20%, it is increased by however much is left up to $100,000. And if two or more employees with the same salary are "the first to be left out", then the "remaining amount" is divided equally between these employees.

```
merge into employees e
  using ( select employee_id,
                 sum  (salary) over (order by salary)     as sum_salary,
                 count(salary) over (partition by salary) as cnt
          from   employees
        ) x
    on ( e.employee_id = x.employee_id )
when matched then update
  set salary = 1.2 * salary + case when sum_salary <= 100000 / 0.2 then 0
                                   else (100000 - 0.2 * sum_salary) / cnt end  
    where sum_salary - cnt * salary <= 100000 / 0.2
;
```